# Custom Json Formatter in .NET Core Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-core, format, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to reduce the size of my response JSON in fact of representing decimal.
Just right now I have a class that is sent a hundred times:

```
public class Article{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    (...)
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The price is automatically sent as "10.000000"
But I want to save (round about 8 KByte!) to shrink just the decimal formatting to "10" or "10.5" and cut away unnecessary zero's.

For this I have to write my own OutputFormatter, but I can just match the whole class structure (which has many more classes) and I don't know how to format dynamically as Json, but just the decimals in right way...

```
public class CustomDecimalFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public string ContentType { get; private set; }

    public CustomDecimalFormatter()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json";
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(decimal);
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var decimalValue = (decimal)context.Object;

        var formatted = decimalValue.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        await response.WriteAsync(formatted);
    }
}
```

How can I make generic Json Response Output and customize just the decimal ones?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not helpful in formatting necessarily, but if all you're trying to do is send decimal with shortened length, why not create a public property instead that returns the same? Something like,

```
class MyClass
{
    private decimal ProductPrice {get;set;}
    public string Price { get { return ProductPrice.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); } }
}
```

This way you can easily tweak your output in the future without changing or impacting majority of your code.

Comment: sounds good, it is just that I "loose" because of the string surrounded double quotes, but already a positive impact. Thank you for that hint!